# UIImageView doesn't scroll

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a image top of the screen and have a collectionview bottom of the imageview. So my problem is, collectionview is scrolling but imageView doesn't scrolling. Its stuck on the top of the page.

I tried to add all views into scroll view but that doesn't help too.
How can i fix that, can anyone help?

```
    private let collectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    return collectionView
}()
private let artistImageView = UIImageView()
private func addImageView() {
    view.addSubview(artistImageView)
    artistImageView.edgesToSuperview(excluding: .bottom, usingSafeArea: true)
    artistImageView.height(400)
    artistImageView.kf.setImage(with: viewModel.artistImage?.convertUrl, placeholder: .none)
    artistImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    artistImageView.clipsToBounds = true
}
private func addCollectionView() {
    view.addSubview(collectionView)
    collectionView.edgesToSuperview(excluding: .top, usingSafeArea: true)
    collectionView.topToBottom(of: artistImageView)
}
```

Comment: So many questions. The code you posted starts in the middle of a method that is not included. What class contains this code? What's the first part of the method shown? What is `view` in your `addImageView()` method? Is that an instance method of a UIViewController? If so, why do you think your image view is being added to a scroll view?

Comment: I don't see a UIScrollView anywhere in your code. Unless you install your image view into a scroll view, there is nothing that would make it scroll.

Comment: @DuncanC This code does not contain UIScrollView.  I added ImageView in UIScrollView but it didn't work so I deleted it and sent the clean version

Comment: We can't help you figure out why your scroll view doesn't scroll if you don't show your scroll view code.

Comment: And what about my other questions?